# WifConfiguration stay connected to LocalOnly hotspot

Tags: android, wifimanager

I'm trying to use an Android App to connect to a temporary hotspot that is used to configure the wifi connected for a seperate device.

I've been able to connect to my temporary hotspot using this snippet

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"SetupNetwork\"";
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wifiManager.disconnect();
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId,true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

The problem is that Android quickly realizes that this network doesn't have an internet connected and decides to "help" by automatically switching back to my old network.

I was considering using

```
conf.priority = 1
```

but priority is not present anymore in API 26.

Comment: Hey, quick question. Are you able to change the WiFi name with this code? And where do you make these calls, before or after calling startLocalOnlyHotspot?

Comment: I'm able to connect to the hotspot on another device with this code.  I was not starting my own hotspot and changing the SSID.

Comment: Okay. In your experience with the API, did you ever have to create a hotspot or face a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and the solution is in your android wifi settings.
You need to turn off intelligent wifi and if you have remembered wifi connections near you you need to turn off the "connect automatically" option in every connection.